# Largest number consists of 1,2,3,4 and generalization?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

It is a question only for fun. Given four digital number $1,2,3,4$ for example, one can use $+,-,\times,\div$ and powers and can only be used for once, and also digit concatenations are allowed, such as $1^{2^{3^4}}$ or $(2^4)^{13}$...

My question is how large the number can be? My guess is the following:

I try to let the power as large as possible so there are two ideal candidates:
$$2^{3^{41}}\text{  v.s.  }2^{4^{31}}$$
By a not so short reasoning, one can find that $3^{41}>4^{31}$. So my largest number so far is $2^{3^{41}}$, it's my guessing work though.

**Generalizations:**

1. Pick any four numbers from $0$ to $9$, is there a universal rule?
2. How about five numbers (this case seems a bit crazy.)?